# Google search autocomplete now displays only a few results (Desktop)

Tags: autocomplete, google-search

[image]

**Before**: In order to get more search autocomplete suggestions (10 instead of 4), one had to disable "Instant search" in the Settings.

**Now**: "Instant search" has been removed by Google a few days ago, and autocomplete is back to only 4 results...

➠ Is there a way to get more search autocomplete results?

Answer (score 2):

**For Chrome:-**
Since this has been changed by Google, the following Chrome extension can be used as an alternative:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/searchbar/fjefgkhmchopegjeicnblodnidbammed

**For Firefox:-**
Still Firefox search bar will display 10 suggestions for a search. Please check [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4ze7.png)

Comment: Nice extension indeed!